# Does Starfleet have their own SEAL Team Six?

Tags: star-trek, starfleet-command

Does Starfleet have a special unit to [carry out black ops missions, counter terrorism, hostage rescue, and special reconnaissance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEAL_Team_Six#Roles_and_responsibilities)?

I don't see Section 31 doing missions like this, S31 seems more like Jason Bourne or Sam Fisher. Usually S31 is a single operative gathering information or carrying out assassinations.

Comment: https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_Special_Operations

Comment: @Valorum - That's really cool. They've never been shown on screen, have they?

Comment: No. Only in books

Comment: MACOs from NX "Enterprise" era?

Comment: Why SEALs?  Why not SBS?

Comment: @NKCampbell - The MACOs were disbanded when Starfleet was created.

Comment: you mean when the Federation was created? Starfleet has always been Starfleet, just a matter of which government it operates under. Without clarification of the question to exclude pre-Federation era, I think MACOs * could * be acceptable

Comment: @NKCampbell - MACOs crossed my mind when I was thinking about this question. I guess they would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a bit like the [Rapid Response Team](https://stexpanded.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_Rapid_Response_Team) from *[The Dominion War Sourcebook: The Fires of Armageddon](http://stevenslong.squarespace.com/star-trek-rpg-free-supplements/)*:

> The Rapid Response Team had a range of functions. During peacetime they were involved in search and rescues, counter-terrorism, disaster relief and special law enforcement. During times of conflict they were tasked with missions behind enemy lines such as reconnaissance, sabotage and deception missions.

Comment: Wow, didn't know they had a RRT. I wonder if any novels that feature them.

Comment: @QueenSvetlana: It may not have existed outside of the pages of the RPG, with this supplement have not been officially published due to the RPG license switching hands.